# how to run a SUMO simulation 100 times automatically (using hand is not allowed)

Tags: python, sumo

I want to run a SUMO simulation consecutively with different scenarios 100 times. I am using my hand to close the GUI while the current run is finished and to start the next simulation. So, I am looking for a way by which there is no need to apply the user's hand even for a short touch between two successive runs by pressing close the GUI of the previous run and starting button for the current run. Your help is appreciated. Regards, Ali p.s. I have just put a loop around my existing script to do the same thing 100 times.

[image: first of all, we need to press the 'yes' bottom to finish the last run]
[image: then, we need to close the GUI to start the new run]
[image: the 'play' bottom should be pressed by hand while I want to do that automatically]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sumo-gui` has the options `--start` and `--quit-on-end` which probably do what you want.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It works very well.